# XCode 4.01 iOS Universal App not showing iPad View

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, xcode4

I am creating a Universal App with XCode support (no unit tests) using XCode 4.01.

In the iPhone folder I create a new UIViewController called iPhoneViewController with XIB.

In xxxAppDelegate_iPhone.h I create a iPhoneViewController instance (called viewController), outlet and property.  In the .m I synthesize the property.

In the xxxAppDelegate_iPhone.m I add the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In IB I open MainWindow_iPhone and add a new View Controller.  I set the view controller class to be iPhoneViewController and type in the XIB name.  I hook up the outlet to the app delegate.

Running the app in Simulator for iPhone - everything works exactly as it is supposed to.

---

Now I add the same type of thing for iPad:

In the iPad folder I create a new UIViewController called iPadViewController with XIB.

In xxxAppDelegate_iPad.h I create a iPadViewController instance (called viewController), outlet and property.  In the .m I synthesize the property.

In the xxxAppDelegate_iPad.m I add the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In IB I open MainWindow_iPad and add a new View Controller.  I set the view controller class to be iPadViewController and type in the XIB name.  I hook up the outlet to the app delegate.

Running the app in Simulator for iPad - the default MainWindow_iPad content is displayed but NOT the new view I added.

I have done this several times - always with the same result.

Debugging:

Setting a breakpoint here in the iPad code:

```
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

viewController is NIL and is never getting loaded.

If I programmatically load from the XIB I can get it to display but it does not fill the entire view.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to connect the window property in IB.

Comment: If you mean the window to Delegate outlet it is connected on both

Comment: Here is the solution.

I moved the addSubView call to awakeFromNib and everything worked as expected.  For some reason the viewController is not instantiated from the XIB when applicaitonDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called (on the iPad version only)